# Unity camera particle system rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem, I have created a particle system and I want to play it on camera in front of everything. How can I do this? If I only position it in front of camera it doesnt look good. It is about a water effect when a player comes out of water.

Answer (score 0):

Prefab>ParticleSystem>Renderer>SortingLayer> here you set it to the highest foreground